# Firebase auth : getIdTokenResult(true) returns expired token after few minutes of inactivity

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

Using Firebase auth from https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase for the react-native project. It works well in all scenarios, handling the token renewal and auth state changes. But when I keep the app open for sometime , and do nothing , or just minimise and come back to the app after 30 mins or 1 hour of inactivity, the

```
firebase
    .auth()
    .currentUser?.getIdTokenResult(true)
```

returns an expired token ( probably it's not refreshing it when i request.

Comment: This sounds like it should be a bug report in that repo you linked.  You should provide full code and instructions on how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, I tried this, but looks like the library is providing a valid token, realised that the  expiry time is provided rightly by the library / internal firebase JS SDK. But this gets invalidated by the server component ( firebase .net sdk). I've raised a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70661222/firebase-idtoken-verification-fails-with-valid-tokens-after-idle-time